# Making glossaires using Texmaker on windows

Tags: texmaker, glossaries

I've been trying for a while to make my glossaries in texmaker.

I've added a user command that is

> latex %
>
> makeglossaries %
>
> latex %

My glossary entries look like this

```
\newglossaryentry{label}
{
 name={name},
description={description}
}
```

I've included the glossaries package and called `\makeglossaries` in my preamble and then called `\printglossaries` before `\end{document}`.

I keep getting errors saying name key required or end up with a page after my table of contents that has "description" written 4 times.

I've read up on the `glossaries` package and read solutions on stack exchange however I'm relativevly new to all of this and can't make sense of any of it.

Could someone explain please?

MWE

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\include{glossaryfile.tex}

\gls{term1} is what I want to display. 

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

then in the glossary file I have

```
  \newglosssaryentry{term1}
    {
    name={term 1},
    description={this is the first term}
    }
```

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: In principle the way you used is the correct one. Perhaps you should read `glossaries-begin.pdf` instead of `glossaries-user.pdf`. The first one is completely sufficent for beginners

Comment: What happens if you use the `\newglossaryentry` in the preamble and omit the `\include` then?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this sooner, I was trying to avoide doing that as I have a large glossary but only a few terms are used. I used \input rather than \include and found I got a new page that just said "description" rather than a glossary. I will try adding the terms into the preamble asap.

Comment: I found the problem, it was the spacing in my glossary entries. Once I made everything on one line in the glossary entries it seemed to work just fine.

Comment: I would recommend looking at `\loadglsentries{glossaryfile}` rather than `input` or `include`.

Answer (score 1):

As is, your MWE will fail because your `\newglossaryentry` call has an extra `s` in it.

The `glossaries` package gives you `\loadglsentries{glossaryfile}` to import your entries cleanly after `\makeglossaries`.

You shouldn't have any problems with new lines and tabs in your `\newglossaryentry`.

With those comments, your MWE becomes

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\loadglsentries{glossaryfile}

\begin{document}


    \gls{term1} is what I want to display. 

    \printglossaries
\end{document}
```

and glossaryfile.tex becomes

```
\newglossaryentry{term1}
{
    name={term 1},
    description={this is the first term}
}
```